# Rails - has_many :through not saving an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

Here are my models and associations:

**project**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_many :projectmemberizations
   has_many :users, :through => :projectmemberizations
   has_many :project_comments
   ...
end
```

**project_comment**

```
class ProjectComment < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :comment, :created_at, :project_id, :user_id, :user_name
   belongs_to :project
   has_many :projectcommentations
   has_many :users, :through => :projectcommentations

   def user
     self.user
   end
end
```

**projectcommentation**

```
class Projectcommentation < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :comment_id, :project_id, :user_id, :user_name
   belongs_to :project_comment
   belongs_to :user
end
```

**user**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account
   has_many :projectmemberizations
   has_many :projects, :through => :projectmemberizations
   has_many :projectcommentations
   has_many :project_comments, :through => :projectcommentations
end
```

### The question

So as you can see, users can comment on a project. That's working fine. But what I'm trying to get working is displaying in the view WHO created a comment. Right now I'm trying to do this and it's not producing any errors, but just not displaying anything for the user_name.

```
<% @project.project_comments.each do |comment|%>
   <div class="comment">
      <%= image_tag current_user.photo.url(:small) %>
      <strong><%= comment.user_name %></strong>
      <%= comment.comment %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Finally, I've got it working in the rails console if I do this:

```
comment = ProjectComment.first
comment.user_id = 1
comment.save
comment.user.name
```

So apparently it's not saving the user_id when adding a comment? Sorry for the length of this by the way!

PS here's she show and new actions in the project_comments controller:

```
def show
    @project_comment = ProjectComment.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project_comment }
    end

  end

  def new
    @project_comment = ProjectComment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project_comment }
    end
  end
```

### ProjectComment create method

```
 def create
    @project_comment = ProjectComment.new(params[:project_comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_url(@project_comment.project_id), :notice => 'Project comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @project_comment, :status => :created, :location => @project_comment }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @project_comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

### Code from view where comment is created

```
<%= form_for(@project_comment) do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @project.id %>
   <%= image_tag current_user.photo.url(:small) %>
   <%= f.text_area :comment, :class => "addcomment" %>
   <%= f.submit :value => "Comment", :class => "tagbtn" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post up the code from the view where the ProjectComment is created? You need to set a user_id there at least or else it won't work. The rails console proves that your associations are working and like @cbascom suggested you have a lot of unnecessary stuff in here. For example, `def user` doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Aaahh that would make sense. I'm only setting the project id and not the user id. So I need to add something like: <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %> which, if I do that, gives me the error "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4"

Comment: Trevan Yeah, you're missing that. Do you have @user defined in your controller?

Comment: In my ProjectComments controller? No. To define that, would it just be something like ```@user = User.all``` in the show action?

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT! I didn't need to define it in the controller, I just needed to save the user_id in a hidden field when submitting the form by doing <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>. It makes sense now. The value has to be the current_user's id. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize you were using current_user instead of user. But glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is currently displaying the contents of comment.user_name.  Your rails console example that is working uses comment.user.name.  You do have user_name in the attr_accessible list of attributes on the ProjectComment model, but none of the posted code fills in a value for that attribute.

I believe from what you are describing that your ProjectCommentation model is unnecessary.  The following models should give you what you are looking for:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :projectmemberizations
    has_many :users, :through => :projectmemberizations
    has_many :project_comments
    ...
end

class ProjectComment < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    attr_accessible :comment, :created_at, :project_id, :user_id, :user_name
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :user
    ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
    has_many :projectmemberizations
    has_many :projects, :through => :projectmemberizations
    has_many :project_comments
end
```

In the ProjectComment controller:

```
def create
    # If params[:project_comment] contains the user_id, it will be set here
    @project_comment = ProjectComment.new(params[:project_comment])

    # If your user id comes from somewhere else (like the user that is signed in)
    @project_comment.user_id = <user id here>

    # Normal save logic here
end
```

Comment: You're right. When I change it to ```comment.user.name```, I get "stack level too dep". Taking out the ```def user``` block in the ProjectComment model gets rid of that stack level error, instead giving me "undefined method `user'"

Comment: Your ProjectComment model currently has_many :users which means the method to access those users is comment.users.  Is each ProjectComment supposed to be associated with only one user using belongs_to instead of has_many?

Comment: Yeah, only one user can belong to a comment. Many users can comment on the project though. So, a ProjectComment belongs_to a user and a user has_many ProjectComments.

Comment: Now that I looked at your comment, I see that what you were saying is the comment.user should be plural. Changing it to plural I get this error: "uninitialized constant ProjectComment::Projectcommentation". Any idea what's causing that? Thanks, @cbascom!

Comment: I edited my original answer to show what I believe your associations should look like based on what you are describing.  Once your associations are set up that way, you should be able to do comment.user.name as you wanted to originally.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So when I use the associations you provided above and do ```comment.user.name```, I get an "undefined method `name'" error still. Do I need to write some more code in the controller to fill that name value? For what it's worth, if I do ```comment.user.id```, I get the error "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id".

Comment: Also, something kind of odd, but if I do ```comment.user_id```, the view displays the number 1 on the very first comment, but none others. It's like it's not looping through or something.

Comment: If comment.user.id is giving you the called id on nil error, it means that your comment is not correctly associated with a user (and this will also cause the undefined method 'name' error).  Any comments that were already created before fixing your associations will have that problem.  In the original question you posted, you executed some code in the rails console that set the user_id to 1 for the very first project comment.  That is why comment.user_id is set correctly for that comment but no others.  If you try comment.user.name for that first comment, it should work as well.

Comment: I created a fresh project. No errors. Then added a comment and got the undefined method for name error. So if my comments aren't correctly associated with the users, wouldn't that be a problem in the model associations? Or does it lie in the ProjectComment controller, where I need to define ```user``` better? Again man, thanks for all your help. If I could pay you through SO I totally would :)

Comment: My guess is the problem is in your ProjectComment controller.  You didn't post your create method from that controller, but in that create method you need to make sure you are setting the user_id and the project_id for the ProjectComment you are creating.

Comment: Updated the post with the create method. Wouldn't I need to do something like: @project_comment = ProjectComment.new(params[:project_comment], :user.id) ?

Comment: See the updated answer for the two possibilities for setting user_id.  If it is supposed to be coming from the view layer, look at your rails log file and make sure you see the user_id in the parameters that are being sent from the form.